# Adding to Linked List

Tags: python, linked-list

I've tried to write a function that takes three parameters: a linked list, a value, and a new value. The purpose of the function is to add the new value after the value in the linked list. Here's my function.

```
def addAfter(lis, value, newValue):
    tracker = lis
    while tracker != None:
        if tracker['data'] == value:
            newNode = {'data':newValue, 'next': tracker['next']}
            tracker['next'] = newNode
            break
        else:
            tracker = tracker['next']
```

For some reason I can't get this function to do anything. It doesn't change the list. I was wondering if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You should add a tag for the language. Is this Python?

Comment: what type of object is `lis`?

Comment: So it's a linked list consisting of dictionaries where the first one is `lis`?

Comment: Can you show how the dictionaries ("nodes") are defined? Maybe the next fields are off. Also what is stored in the list? Maybe your == or hash is evaluating in weird ways

Comment: Make sure you remove any `.pyc` files in your directory and try again.

Comment: Linked Lists are defined as follows: {'data':value, 'next':nextnode} Yeah its a linkedlist consisting of dictionaries and the first one is lis

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably in how you're defining your initial nodes or list. For example, the following code works in Python3.4

```
def addAfter(lis, value, newValue):
    tracker = lis
    while tracker != None:
        if tracker['data'] == value:
            newNode = {'data':newValue, 'next': tracker['next']}
            tracker['next'] = newNode
            break
        else:
            tracker = tracker['next']

node1 = {'data':3,'next':None}
addAfter(node1,3,4)

print(node1)
print(node1['next'])
```

This outputs

```
{'next': {'next': None, 'data': 4}, 'data': 3}
{'next': None, 'data': 4}
```

As we'd expect it to. So there are several possibilities here

- You're not using dictionaries at all - you defined a custom class and overloaded the **setitem** and **getitem**. I highly doubt this
- You overloaded equals or hash so that the evaluations aren't correct. Doubt this too
- You're using non-built-in objects as values and didn't overload the equals, so when you compare Foo() to Foo() it evaluates false. This seems somewhat likely. You might *think* that things are equal, when in fact Python is checking if they lie at the same memory location, not that their fields match
- Your test code is wrong, you're printing out a copy of the data not the original data. This sort of thing is always a possibility

Try testing for each of those and let us know if none pan out. If not, provide a little more context, i.e., a scenario where the break is evident

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a new class such as :

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None
```

and then use the code of en_Knight, otherwise, the code will be hard to read